# PowerShell Display 2 Objects side-by-side under one column

Tags: powershell, object

Trying to figure out how use PowerShell Studio to display two objects side by side as shown below, left side being the domain and right side is the user name:

Example:

`CP Administrator
CP LocalAdmin
CP OtherAdmin`

However, it's displaying the two in one column like below:

Results:

`Users:
CP
CP
CP
Administrator
LocalAdmin
OtherAdmin`

This is the script I have going so far and tried a few things I found online but it's not working the way I was hoping for. Am I missing something simple?

```
$FQDN = $rtxtComputerName.Text
$GroupAndUsers = Get-LocalGroupMember -Computername $FQDN

$Domain = $GroupAndUsers | ?{ $_.Group –match "Administrators" -and $_.Class -eq "User" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domain
$Name = $GroupAndUsers | ?{ $_.Group –match "Administrators" -and $_.Class -eq "User" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$Users = ($Domain + $Name)

foreach ($Line in $Users)
{
    $rtxtServerUsers.Lines += "$Line"
}
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What's the purpose of the script? List members of a computer's local `Administrators` group?

Comment: `$rtxtServerUsers.Lines = $GroupAndUsers | ?{ $_.Group –match "Administrators" -and $_.Class -eq "User" } | %{"$($_.Domain) $($_.Name)"}`

Comment: The output from `$GroupAndUsers | ?{ $_.Group –match "Administrators" -and $_.Class -eq "User" } | Select-Object Domain,Name` will be formatted and display like you describe by default

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Purpose is to list the members from a server that's are admins

Comment: @BenH - OMG that's perfect!!!! Thank you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Yes under ISE it works, however in Studio, it didn't display side-by-side, but rather all in one column like the result shown above